# C# class object error as unassigned local Variable

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ans MS SQL 2012 for database in my Windows form Application C#. I am stuck with this error unassigned local Variable

```
private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //SqlFunctions obj  = null;
    SqlFunctions obj  ;

    if (txtBox_LoginID.Text !="" && txtBox_LoginPassword.Text !="")
    {
        if (obj.loginCheck(int.Parse(txtBox_LoginID.Text), txtBox_LoginPassword.Text)== 1)
        {
            pnl_loginCheck.BackColor = Color.DarkGreen;
            lbl_login.ForeColor = Color.White;
            lbl_login.Text = "User ID And Password You Entered Is Correct";
            lbl_login.Font = new Font(lbl_login.Font.FontFamily, 22);
        }
```

When I run the program I got error `unassigned local Variable`.
and when I initialize the

```
SqlFunctions obj = null;
```

I got error unhandled null reference exception at

```
if (obj.loginCheck(int.Parse(txtBox_LoginID.Text), txtBox_LoginPassword.Text)== 1)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First error at SqlFunctions obj  ;

Comment: Do not store passwords in plain text.

Comment: You need an instance of your class.  Although it sounds like you actually want static methods.

Comment: i am using static methods but there is a problem with static methods. I cam't use them

Comment: Your methods are not marked as static in your code example. You need the `static` keyword. In any case, you would then use `SqlFunctions.MyMethod()` instead of the variable `obj`

Comment: How should i store passwords @SLaks

Comment: @MuhammadHannan: Use PBKDFv2.

Comment: Can you @SLaks Guide me more. I have no idea about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `SqlFunctions obj =  new SqlFunctions();`

Comment: Sure i will Before it stops giving me time warning :P

Comment: @MuhammadHannan what kind of warning ?